# How to share smart home app to other users before it published?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I am developing a smart home app and want to share it to another Google account before it published.

I follow the steps in https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/testing-deploying#sharing_your_project
Add a new member xxx@gmail.com and role set to project -> viewer.

But my smart home app does not appear in the home control section of Google Home app when I use the Google account xxx@gmail.com.

When I switch back to my own Google account, my smart home app appears in the Google Home app.
Is anyone encountering this issue?

Comment: did you find anything regarding this?

Comment: @AarthTandel I am not sure if this problem still exists coz my smart home app was published already. Do you still encounter this issue?

Comment: Yes, I still have the issue, I added owners but the test application only shows up on my phone.

Comment: @AarthTandel When AoG team reviews my app, they ask me to share the app to them in the same way, and it works for them. Maybe you can try to reach out for the AoG support team? I think this issue may need help from Google directly.

Answer (score 0):

For sharing your smart home actions with other users, follow theses steps,

- Click the "3-dots" icon in the upper right corner of the console (https://console.actions.google.com/)
- Click Manage user access (this redirects you to the Google Cloud Platform IAM permissions page)
- Click ADD at the top of the page
- Enter the email address of the user you want to add
- Click Select a role and choose Project > Viewer
- Click SAVE

In order to add users to a project, you need to be an owner of the project and after you're done with the above steps then all the added users will be able to see the Actions on their Google console. Additionally the users that have shared access to your Action can test it on Assistant-enabled devices such as their smartphones. But, before they can test the smart home Action, the added users must set up for testing. In order to test that Action device testing must be enabled for that device and after doing that it should be linked to the correct Google account. Performing this setup allows users to test on Google Assistant surfaces and on the Google Home app, using the same account you used to sign in to the Actions console.  Find out more about setting up testing at https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/testing?hl=en#setup